# matrix of the dual representation: inverse of the transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, solution-verification

I have a doubt concerning the dual representation. Can someone check that what I wrote is correct please?

Let $A: V \to V$ be linear, the dual map $A^T : V^* \to V^*$ is defined by
$$ A^*(f)(x)=f(A(x))$$
or in other words,
$$ \langle{A^Tf,x}\rangle=\langle{f,Ax}\rangle $$ 
Let $e_i$ be a basis for $V$ and $e^i$ its dual basis
$$ \langle{A^T e^i,e_j}\rangle=\langle{e^i,Ae_j}\rangle=A_{ji}$$
We get the transposed matrix.

Now let $\rho: G \to \text{GL}(V) $ be a representation. The dual representation
$$ \rho: G \to \text{GL}(V^*) $$
is given by
$$ \rho^*(g)=\rho(g^{-1})^T $$
where the inverse insures that one gets a homomorphism. Relatively to the same bases, one gets

\begin{align*}
\langle{\rho^*(g) e^i,e_j}\rangle
&=\langle{\rho^T(g^{-1}) e^i,e_j}\rangle \\
&=\langle{e^i,\rho(g^{-1}) e_j}\rangle\\
&=\rho(g)^{-1}_{ji} 
\end{align*}
the inverse of the transpose.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, but note that your last notation $\rho(g)_{ij}^{-1}$ is ambiguous while $\rho(g^{-1})_{ij}$ is not.

Comment: Indeed, thanks.

Comment: I am wondering why it is $A_{ji}$ instead of $A_{ij}$?